# How to set individual capability of post type in individual category

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities

I need to add a new post type "Story". Each of my users I will give them an individual role to edit/view their own "Story"(One user one role). User Role only gives ability to limit capabilities based on post type. Is there a way to limit even further on categories of the post type?

Or is there an alternative way to do something similar?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.